# Parallel Invocation of Lambda functions by another lambda function asynchronously in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless-framework-step-functions

I have a master lambda function (say X) which calls another lambda function (say Y) asynchronously. Once one instance of lambda function Y is triggered and executed it dumps data to kinesis or s3 and then there is the final lambda function (say Z) which takes that data from kinesis or s3 and as input and gets triggered. This is the entire flow process and the process is completely event driven.

Now the master function (X) is triggered with different inputs for each run. For the first lambda function call (Y) it creates as many number instances as the input to the master and different AWS request id for each instance. But for the second slave lambda function (Z) this is not being created. It is creating only one aws request id (which means the process is not asynchronous). But if I assign a wait time of 20 seconds to the master lambda function (X) then this problem is no more there. I am using Python 3.6 for the process .

Why does this happen ? Is this a known issue ? Is there any better approach to do the same thing to achieve the complete end-to-end flow process ?

This the code for my master lambda function(X):

***************************sample code***********************************

```
def master_handler(event, context):
"""
Function to trigger slave code
"""
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    aws_request_id = context.aws_request_id
    inputs = ['abc','def','ghi']
    for i in inputs:
        payload = {'current_input': '{}'.format(i),
                   'parent_aws_request_id': '{}'.format(aws_request_id)
                  }
        client.invoke(
            FunctionName=<slave function name>,
            InvocationType='Event',
            Payload=json.dumps(payload)
        )
        print(f"Trigger executed for {i}")
    print(f"Master function execution completed!")
```

Comment: Is it possible you have maxed out the 1000 max parallel executions per account? Or do you maybe use Reserved Capacity for any of the functions?

Comment: No is only executes 5 paralle invocations from the master function.